# Where does the data node inside the API method catalogProductLinkAssign get extracted?

Tags: api, soap-api-v2

I am trying to find out where the "data" array, specifically the "position" value inside the "data" array gets extracted from a catalogProductLinkAssign Magento SOAP API V2 web service call and subsequently saved inside magento.

The relevant documentation indicating the node I am talking about is here:  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalog_product_link.assign.html

You can see reference to a node called catalogProductLinkEntity which contains a array called "data".  Inside this array is the string value called "position".

Where in the magento source code tree is this value extracted?
The closest I have been able to get is to this file (\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Api\V2.php)  but can't see where the position value itself is extracted, just a value called code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the details that pointed me in the right direction on this page here:

http://joshpennington.com/an-overview-of-magentos-get-and-set-methods/

There is a function called setGroupedLinkData that you can call on the magento catalog/product model to create the "Associated Product" links with quantity and position, but as this method doesn't exist it ends up propagating through to the top object Varien_Object where it is handled via the magic function "__call".